# how to convert age in year, month, day to year with decimal

Tags: r, date, decimal

Suppose I have a string

```
   age<-c("7y2m4d","5m4d","7y5m6d")
```

I want to convert it to a numeric vector like

```
  c(7.34, 0.43, 7.43)
```

How can I make the R code?

We can assume there is 365 days in a year and 365/12 days in a month.

Comment: I am not sure that this can be done accurately without dates. Months have differing numbers of days and so can years, so how do you convert months to days, sum that with days and divide by days in a year without knowing which months and years the period spans?

Comment: yes, we can assume there is 365 days in a year and 365/12 days in a month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with base R:

```
age<-c("7y2m4d","5m4d","7y5m6d")


age <- gsub('y', ' + ', age)
age <- gsub('m', ' / 12 + ', age)
age <- gsub('d', ' / 365', age)

sapply(age, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
#7 + 2 / 12 + 4 / 365     5 / 12 + 4 / 365 7 + 5 / 12 + 6 / 365 
#           7.1776256            0.4276256            7.4331050
```

The idea is to create the formula and then evaluate it for each element of your vector.

Answer (score 3):

`lubridate::duration` will convert your strings to (approximate) seconds.

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
age <- c("7y2m4d", "5m4d", "7y5m6d")

age_sec <- age %>%
  duration() %>%
  as.numeric()

age_sec
[1] 226508400  13494600 234570600
```

Then you can approximate years as `365 * 24 * 60 * 60` seconds:

```
age_sec / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
[1] 7.182534 0.427911 7.438185
```

Comment: Make sure you add `dplyr` or `magrittr` in your answer for `%>%` and also you don't need `sapply` here. Just use the vectorised way `age_sec / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)`

Comment: Right, the `sapply` was a hangover from exploration :)

Answer (score 2):

These solutions:

- handle missing y, m and/or d and
- give the same answer as in the question (except for the first element of `age` for which the question appears to have computed the answer incorrectly)
- avoid the use of eval
- only use base (except for alternative 1a)

Comparing the solutions below on the basis of simplicity (1a) is the simplest and automatically handles all the edge cases without specific code for them suggesting that it is the most natural; however, it does make use of a package.  (1) is only slightly more complex and uses no packages and (2) pretty short and also does not use any packages but it is not as simple as (1) or (1a).

**1)** Here `getNum` extracts and returns the number from `x` associated with the code (the code is "y", "m" or "d") or if the code is not present in `x` returns 0.  We then add up the year, month/12 and day/365.

```
getNum <- function(code, x) {
  pat <- sprintf(".*?(\\d+)%s.*", code)
  as.numeric(ifelse(grepl(code, x), sub(pat, "\\1", x), 0))
}
getNum("y", age) + getNum("m", age) / 12 + getNum("d", age) / 365
## [1] 7.1776256 0.4276256 7.4331050
```

**1a)**  This is similar to (1) except that we use strapply in gsubfn to simplify `getNum`.  In fact `getNum` reduces to a single `strapply` call and the regular expression it uses is also simpler.

```
library(gsubfn)

 getNum <- function(code, x) {
   strapply(x, paste0("(\\d+)", code), as.numeric, empty = 0, simplify = TRUE)
 }
getNum("y", age) + getNum("m", age) / 12 + getNum("d", age) / 365
## [1] 7.1776256 0.4276256 7.4331050
```

**2)** This alternative converts each string to dcf format and uses read.dcf to create a matrix of the y, m and d numbers.

In detail, the first line of code is to handle certain edge cases which are not actually present in the sample data in the question. We first append 0d to `age` (from the question) if d is missing so that we can handle the case where y, m and d are all missing.  We also prepend a dummy entry to ensure that y, m and d are present in at least one entry.  If we knew that y, m and d were present in at least one component and there was no component in which y, m and d were all simultaneously missing then this first line of code could be omitted.

The second line of code converts each input character string to dcf form and reads it into a matrix ensuring that the columns are in a known order and deleting the dummy entry added above.

Finally we replace NAs with 0 and and use matrix multiplication to add up the year, month/12 and day/365.

```
a0 <- c("0y0m0d", paste0(age, ifelse(grepl("d", age), "", "0d")))
m <- read.dcf(textConnection(gsub("(\\d+)(\\D)", "\\2: \\1\n", a0)))[-1, c("y", "m", "d")]
m[is.na(m)] <- 0
c(array(as.numeric(m), dim(m)) %*% c(1, 1/12, 1/365))
## [1] 7.1776256 0.4276256 7.4331050
```

**Update:** Rearranged and added (1) and (1a).